# Linq.Expressions question - three parameters?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I am trying to replicate the statement using *System.Linq.Expressions* in Entity Framework Core.

```
MyDbSet.Select(x => x.MyIntField, x.MyStringField1, x.MyStringField2)
```

I have a basic example that is returning the lambda  ***x => x.MyIntField***, but can't find an example of adding the two extra parameters.

I can create the individual properties x.myStringField1, x.MyStringField2, but not sure how to combine them into the lambda.

My test statement is:

```
var lambdaExpr = Expression.Lambda<Func<T,String>>( firstProperty, firstParameter);
```

So my question is how to extend this to accept the secondProperty and thirdProperty items?

Comment: Do you mean `MyDbSet.Select(x => (x.MyIntField, x.MyStringField1, x.MyStringField2))`?

Comment: That is the desired result.  Using an extension method on the MyDbSet called GetData(this IQueryable<T> query, int myIntField, String myStringField1, String myStringField2)  and returning query.Select(lambdaExpr);   the best I can get is  x => x.MyIntField.  Adding the brackets and the extra fields from your example is proving interesting.

Comment: For which purpose? Serialization? I'm ask because dynamic generation query will become unusable without later dynamic processing.

Comment: no, dynamic query on unknown column names (using reflection to create a LINQ Select(x,y,z) statement..   It works fine with one column, just can't figure out how to generate the syntax for returning multiple columns.

Comment: How do you plan to manipulate with query later?

Comment: Sorry, don't understand the question, it is just generating a select statement as in  var rec = dc.MyTable.Select(x => x.myIntField, x.MyStringField1, x.MyStringField2) .ToList() - there is nothing to manipulate.  The value of rec will be a list of anonymous types as per normal.

Comment: List of something anonymous, which compiler cannot predict. It should be serialized later for API call or displayed on the UI.